# php: array_unique missing a duplicate

Tags: php, unique-array

I have been struggling with a minor issue with the array_unique for a couple of days now.

Somehow the output always leaves the last duplicate in the array.

I am getting the text from a text box in an html form

```
$IDs = trim($_POST['IDs']);
$IDs = explode("\n", $IDs);
$IDs = array_filter($IDs, 'trim');
$ID = array_unique($IDs,0);
print_r($ID);
```

sample input:

`012345
0123456
01234567
012345
0123456
01234567
012345
0123456
01234567`
sample output:

```
Array ( [0] => 012345 [1] => 0123456 [2] => 01234567 [3] => 01234567 )
```

sample input:

`012345
0123456
01234567
012345
0123456
01234567
012345
0123456`
sample output:

```
Array ( [0] => 012345 [1] => 0123456 [2] => 01234567 [3] => 0123456 )
```

not sure why the last duplicate keeps getting missed.

Am sure I am missing something but cannot seem to figure it out.

Added the foreach loop hoping to fix it but even with that I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `isset($k[$v]) || ($k[$v]=1) && $ID[] = $v;`?

Comment: even without the loop, I was missing the duplicate. Thought if I just loop through it again, the problem with will resolved but it didnt. even if I dont run the loop the issue remains.

Comment: isset($k[$v]) || ($k[$v]=1).... this will always evaluate to true, since you are setting $k[$v] = 1. Maybe $k[$v] == 1

Comment: This is just a guess. But looking at your sample input, both the final values in each array seem to have a trailing space, which if true, will make them unique. The first values in both the inputs seem to have a space preceding them as well.

Comment: k, loop removed. the issue remains.

Comment: nice catch, wouldnt the trim have fixed it? Also I think all of them have a space at the end. so dont think its that issue.

Comment: @rm65453 yeah you're right. It should have

Comment: https://eval.in/649279     .this is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead of `array_filter`.

Like:

```
$IDs = trim($_POST['IDs']);
$IDs = explode("\n", $IDs);
$IDs = array_map('trim', $IDs);
$ID = array_unique($IDs,0);
print_r($ID);
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks to @kkaosninja as well for pointing out the space thing. Google did bring up the issues with array_filter vs array_map.

Comment: Without knowing the value of `$_POST['IDs']` how did you answered this question?

Answer (score -1):

I have corrected your data format and `foreach()` is unnecessary:-

```
<?php

$IDs = "012345\n0123456\n01234567\n012345\n0123456\n01234567\n012345\n0123456\n01234567";

$IDs = explode("\n", $IDs);
$IDs = array_unique($IDs,0);

print_r($IDs);

?>
```

and the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 012345
    [1] => 0123456
    [2] => 01234567
)
```

P.S. I realized that also `array_filter` was unnecessary.

Comment: @Anant I didn't change array structure. Formatting of the input in the question was faulty/wrong.

Comment: not sure where you made the changes. could you highlight them?

Comment: @mertyildiran IRL you don't always have control over inputs used.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg Then give me the input in correct formatting please.

Comment: The input is coming from a text box. might be the correct answer but does not work for me due to my restrictions on the input.

Comment: @rm65453 You gave us the string `012345\n0123456\n01234567\n012345\n0123456\n01234567\n012345\n0123456\n01234567` in your question as the value of `$_POST['IDs']`. So you formatting was wrong on your question.

Comment: the string was entered in a text box. you are correct with the string that you were providing but that was the whole issue. Somehow it was not behaving the way it should have the filters.

Comment: @rm65453 I have flagged your question because: "This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed." You were need to give us the output of `echo $_POST['IDs'];` in correct formatting.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @mertylildiran sure if thats what you want. most of the users were able to figure out what was going on. Anyways my issue has been resolved and hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: @rm65453 I couldn't. Please learn how to format your posts properly.